Send events to Google Tag Manager when Google Sign-in button is clicked
I'm working on implementing custom events in Google Tag Manager for my website, and it’s mostly going well — except for one issue. I'm trying to trigger a GTM event when the Google Sign-in button is clicked. Typically, for other buttons on the site, I can simply add an onclick function to initiate the event, but the Google Sign-in button behaves differently.
Since it’s rendered using Google’s API (as shown in the code below), I haven’t been able to attach event listeners or directly manipulate its DOM elements to trigger the GTM event. Does anyone know of a way to set up a GTM event for clicks on Google-rendered buttons like this?
Here is the cshtml that renders the button:
<div class="login-form-group">
    @{
        var clientId = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google:ClientId").Value;
        <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
        <div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id=@clientId data-callback="googleCallbackHandler"
            data-auto_prompt="false" data-ux-mode="redirect" data-use_fedcm_for_prompt="false">
        </div>
        <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" data-size="large" data-theme="filled_blue" 
            data-text="sign_in_with" data-shape="rectangular" data-logo_alignment="left"
            data-locale="en" type="submit">
        </div>
    }
</div>

And here is the javascript code I've tried using for triggering the event:
const googleButton = document.getElementsByClassName("login-form-group")[0];
if(googleButton) {
    console.log("googleButton exists")
    googleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("googleButton was clicked")
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'googleButtonClick'
        });
        console.log("googleButtonClick event sent");
    })
}

The first console log is executed, but not the second or third. I've tried giving the parent div its own ID and using that to attach the event listener, but that didn't work either. Neither did attaching event listeners to the child elements that are rendered by Google and thus can't be found in my html.
This is how the button looks in the DOM

Show how the button looks in the DOM. Also, I'd expect the google button to send dataLayer pushes out of the box. It doesn't do that?

@BNazaruk I've now added an image of what the button looks like in the DOM. As far as I know, the google button doesn't send dataLayer pushes out of the box, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

As expected, that button is in an iframe. You won't be able to listen to clicks on it with your typical GTM listeners.
What you can hope for is that that button communicates to the parent when the clicks happen. Deploy a window messages listener logging every message and try clicking on the button. See if it communicates to the page on clicks.
It should. It's a good tone for an iframe solutions like this to communicate the interactions to the parent.
If it does, you can then use that listener to do dataLayer pushes.

I added a window messages listener and tried clicking the button. I receive an event from the iframe when the page loads, but unfortunately nothing when I click the button.

uh... Not much you can do then. You may use a different front-end solution, but there's no way to track iframe interactions from the parent if iframe doesn't communicate them. Shame on Google for not doing it. Don't they offer a different solution for that button for people who don't want iframes?

It looks like using iframes is by far the most common way, but I'll look into alternative approaches. Thanks for your input!
